# What is the process to inscribe a circle in an isosceles trapezoid?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Basically the question.

I have tried to follow similar steps which are used to inscribe a circle in a triangle (bisect any two angles and the intersection of the bisectors is the centre of the circle), but bisecting any of the angles of the isosceles trapezoid gives an intersection that is a bit off and the circle goes outside of the trapezoid.

Diagram would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not every isosceles trapezoid has an inscribed circle. See Pitot's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_theorem#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20the%20Pitot%20theorem,the%20semiperimeter%20of%20the%20quadrilateral.

Comment: Is a circle inscribed if it is tangent to just two sides of the trapezoid?

Comment: Where did you get the trapezoid and why do you want to inscribe a circle in it?

Comment: If the trapezoid is a kind in which a circle can be inscribed (so that the circle is tangent to all four sides), the "any two **adjacent** angles" method works. (Don't try it with opposite angles.) "Most" isosceles trapezoids do not have this property, however. And even when the trapezoid does have the property, if you are doing this with actual pencil and paper it can be hard to execute the steps as accurately as you might desire.

Comment: Numerical analysis based solution: Possible value for radius of circle (per a geometric proof): r = 1/2*square root (base1*base2). Use this to center the circle at the origin on graph paper. Equation for circle: x^2+y^2=r^2. Find the slope and two points from line connecting the 2 bases. Determine therefrom the equation of the line. Replace y with  this linear function of x in circle equation. Solve by Quadratic formula. Note should only have a single root or otherwise the circle is cut (2 roots) or untouched (no real roots). Not theoretically elegant but likely links to such. Tedious work

Comment: Continuing comment on actually a geometric and numerical analysis based solution path, which by the way, having performed a related analysis for a circle inscribed in a right triangle, attempting a general formula solution is a bit much, in my opinion, and not likely producing an easy to apply answer anyway,. On the solution path, there are four touching lines, but  by a symmetry argument, being a isosceles trapezoid, may have to investigate, per above, 2 cases, albeit the case I focused on is likely enough. Here is a link: https://www.geogebra.org/m/vu5jwc7r to finding r

Comment: Define the inscribed circle - if touches the two basis than the radius is half the height.